# how can i build this function that takes an array of tree object and concatenates them into one tree object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, tree

I'm trying to write a function called buildTree() that takes the following datastructure as an input, loops on every element to output a tree of a specific format:
this is an example of my datastructure:

```
let array =  [
      {
        levelOne: [
          {
            id: 'a',
            rowData: {}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        levelOne: [
          {
            id: 'b',
            children: {
              levelTwo: [
                {
                  id: 'c',
                  rowData: {}
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        levelOne: [
          {
            id: 'b',
            children: {
              levelTwo: [
                {
                  id: 'd',
                  rowData: {}
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

if we pass the array to buildTree()

```
 let result = this.buildTree(array);
```

the result should hold the following tree:

```
{
         levelOne: [
          {
            id: 'a',
            rowData: {}
          },
           {
            id: 'b',
            children: {
              levelTwo: [
                {
                  id: 'c',
                  rowData: {}
                },
                {
                  id: 'd',
                  rowData: {}
                }
//two elements in this array since they share the id             
 ]
            }
          }
        ]
    }
```

another example would be:

```
let array2 = [
      {
        levelOne: [
          {
            id: 'a',
            rowData: {}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        levelOne: [
          {
            id: 'a',
            children: {
              levelTwo: [
                {
                  id: 'b',
                  rowData: {}
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        levelOne: [
          {
            id: 'a',
            children: {
              levelTwo: [
                {
                  id: 'b',
                  children: {
                    levelThree: [
                      {
                        id: 'c',
                        rowData: {}
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        levelOne: [
          {
            id: 'a',
            children: {
              levelTwo: [
                {
                  id: 'b',
                  children: {
                    levelThree: [
                      {
                        id: 'd',
                        rowData: {}
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

let result2 = this.buildTree(array2)
```

result2 should hold :

```
 {
        levelOne: [
          {
            id: 'a',
            rowData: {},
            children: {
              levelTwo: [
                {
                  id: 'b',
                  rowData: {},
                   children: {
                    levelThree: [
                      {
                        id: 'c',
                        rowData: {}
                      },
                       {
                        id: 'd',
                        rowData: {}
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

keeping in mind that if two elements in array had the same id , then they should fall under the same children of their key in the result like shown in the example.

i wrote a helper function to get me the element on a specific level called getElementByLevel():

```
 getElementByLevel(tree: any, level: number , count = 0){
    // debugger;
    if(tree){
    let key = Object.keys(tree)[0]
    let element = tree[key][0];
    if(count<level){
      count=count+1
     return this.getElementByLevel(element.children,level , count)
    }
    else {
      return element;
    }
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }

  }
```

and this is my unworking incomplete buildTree() function:

```
buildTree(mainArray: any[]){

    let myTree = {};
  mainArray.forEach((item , index) => {

    if(index == 0){
      myTree = {...item};
      console.log(myTree);
    }

    else
    {

      debugger;
      let myElement = this.getElementByLevel(myTree, 0);
      let elementToAdd = this.getElementByLevel(mainArray[1],0 )
      myElement = {...myElement, ...elementToAdd}
      console.log(myElement);
      myTree = myElement;
    }

  
  })

  

  }
```

more info about the input datastructure:

-rowData is always on the final level of the tree.

-arrays of 'levelOne','levelTwo','levelThree' etc.. are singletons holding one object (only in the input)

-the keys ('levelOne','levelTwo','levelThree' etc..) are dynamic keys and need to remain in the datastructure as shown in the examples.

more info about the output tree:

-the elements with the same id and the same parent key(eg. levelOne) must have their children as siblings. an example of that is -array[1].levelOne[0]- and -array[2].levelOne[0]- resulting in sibling children in -result-

any ideas on how to build the buildTree() function would be appreciated

Comment: Wow ... Could you simply a bit the dataStructure for us ? Like for the 'id' thing just go for 1, 2, 3 maybe it could help getting what you want and just get rid of the rowData if they don't get involved aswell ^^' ... Because for now I don't get which ids are "shared"

Comment: That's an inefficient data structure to go for. "levelOne", "levelTwo", "levelThree" is information that is not needed. The level is clear without that. You should just let `children` be that array. And better than an array: an object whose properties are named by the `id` values.

Comment: It would really help if you simplified your sample data.  We don't need 64-byte keys.  3 or 4 would do fine.  `rowData: {a: 'a 1', b: 'b 1', c: 'c 1'}` would be plenty.  Moreover, beyond the excellent suggestion from trincot, you still need to explain exactly *how* things are to be combined.  Do we combine only keys with "level" in their name?  What do we do if we have `rowData` twice for the same tree position, merge them?

Comment: "levelOne", "levelTwo" , "levelThree" are dynamic keys that need to stay in the datastructure , they serve a bit like IDs that come from the serverside. rowData is given only once per element in the array and it's always on the final level

Comment: "levelOne", "levelTwo" , "levelThree" don't look that dynamic to me. It seems "levelOne" is always the name at level 1, "levelTwo" is always the name at level 2, ...etc. That is just duplication of information that is already there.

Comment: @trincot the function buildTree() needs to treat them as dynamic because they could be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use recursion to first build a tree that has the `id` values as keys (for fast lookup in case of multiple occurrences of the same `id`). Then in a second phase you can then transform that structure so it has the "levelXXX" values as arrays -- which are not suitable for fast lookup by `id`:

```js
function buildTree(array) {

    function mergeByKeys(levelItem, result) {
        for (let levelKey in levelItem) {
            let idItems = result[levelKey] = result[levelKey] || {};
            for (let {id, children, rowData} of levelItem[levelKey]) {
                let item = idItems[id] = idItems[id] || {id};
                if (children) item.children = mergeByKeys(children, item.children || {});
                if (rowData) item.rowData = rowData;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    function levelsToArrays(levelItem) {
        for (let levelKey in levelItem) {
            for (let { children } of (levelItem[levelKey] = Object.values(levelItem[levelKey]))) {
                if (children) levelsToArrays(children);
            }
        }
    }

    let result = {};
    for (let levelItem of array) mergeByKeys(levelItem, result);
    levelsToArrays(result);
    return result;
}

// Example 2:
let array2 = [{levelOne: [{id: 'a',rowData: {}}]},{levelOne: [{id: 'a',children: {levelTwo: [{id: 'b',rowData: {}}]}}]},{levelOne: [{id: 'a',children: {levelTwo: [{id: 'b',children: {levelThree: [{id: 'c',rowData: {}}]}}]}}]},{levelOne: [{id: 'a',children: {levelTwo: [{id: 'b',children: {levelThree: [{id: 'd',rowData: {}}]}}]}}]}];

let result2 = buildTree(array2)
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: I tried to hard to do it in a single pass, even when everything was pointing toward something like this.  Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the correct structure you're searching for?

Input:

```
let structure = [
  {
    one: {
      id: 'ISBWIS',
      rowData: 346234,
      children: [
        {
          two: {
            id: 'UUEJSW',
            rowData: 958793
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    one: {
      id: 'KSDIWG',
      rowData: 857262,
      children: [
        {
          two: {
            id: 'XJSHWQ',
            rowData: 855582
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    one: {
      id: 'ISBWIS',
      children: [
        {
          two: {
            id: 'KNWEJD',
            rowData: 181132
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    one: {
      id: 'ISBWIS',
      children: [
        {
          two: {
            id: 'KNWEJD',
            children: [
              {
                three: {
                  id: 'JEISYS',
                  rowData: 454933
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

Output:

```
{
    "one": [
        {
            "id": "ISBWIS",
            "rowData": 346234,
            "children": {
                "two": [
                    {
                        "id": "UUEJSW",
                        "rowData": 958793
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "KNWEJD",
                        "rowData": 181132,
                        "children": {
                            "three": [
                                {
                                    "id": "JEISYS",
                                    "rowData": 454933
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "KSDIWG",
            "rowData": 857262,
            "children": {
                "two": [
                    {
                        "id": "XJSHWQ",
                        "rowData": 855582
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Wissam: This is certainly not an answer, but it looks as though typable was simply trying to do the simplification I suggested.  While your edit to the question moved in this direction, it didn't go as far as this suggestion.  Is there anything substantial different outside the names of the properties and the simplification of `rowData`?

Comment: @typable: it looks to be missing a level of arrays in the input.  `one`, `two`, etc are arrays holding (single?) objects, not just objects.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes arrays in the input data structure are singletons and hold only one element. I added more relevant details to the question that i didn't pay attention to, thank you for pointing it out. and yes what's inside rowData is irrelevant aswell